# How to do webscrapping in R on this webpage?

Tags: r, scraping

I am quite new to R and I am trying to learn webscraping. I basically need to extract documents from [this website](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2019/html/index.en.html.).

Ideally, the data needs to be structured in three columns: YEAR, DATE, and
INTRODUCTORYSTATEMENT_CONTENT. Can anyone help with the coding?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with  rvest in R. Two things make is possible

1. URL pattern is predictable, https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2012/html/index.en.html    (replace 2012 with other year values)
2. Html page applies predictable CSS for INTRODUCTORYSTATEMENT_CONTENT (E.g.: doc-title and doc-subtitle )

[image]

Following articles have examples :

https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-tutorial-in-r-5e71fd107f32
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!